# How to customize boostrap3 colum to 70px width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I try, to customize boostrap colum to 70px width. 
Now, i have col-lg-1 column 64.984px width, i need 70px. 
How to do that in Boostrap 3. I use standart 1170 container.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-1">I am 64px width block</div>
    <!-- /.col-xl-1 -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I change container size to 1201px

Answer (score 0):

You can set width manually as follows:

```
<div class="col-xl-1" style="width:70px"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad, i will clarify, they should be a luqiud size, in 1170 container

Comment: "col-xl-1" has its own width by default. Adding inline style to it will override its default width.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that whenever you will call col-xl-1 the width will be 70% then go to bootstrap.css file. Search for col-xl-1 & change

```
.col-xl-1 {
  width: 64.984px%;
}
```

to

```
.col-xl-1 {
  width: 70%;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad, i will clarify, they should be a luqiud size, in 1170 container.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap's grid its based on flexbox. All you need to do is add custom class and set flex-basis attribute.

```css
.custom {
  flex-basis: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-1 custom">I am 64px width block</div><!-- /.col-xl-1 -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: _“Bootstrap's grid its based on flexbox.”_ - not in BS 3, which is what OP is using here.